# AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag' in Python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I want to parse an XML file and extract the nodes that I am interested in if the nodes contain a specific string (keyword). But to use find and finall functions, first I decided to lower case the list of the keywords that I have, as well as the XML file.
Here is code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring
import csv
tree=ET.parse('/Users/m/Documents/dr.xml')
**t = tostring(tree)**
t = t.lower()
tree= ET.fromstring(t).......
```

I get error on this line:

```
t = tostring(tree)
```

Any idea how this can be fixed?
Thx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to parse it from the [root node](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring

tree = ET.parse('t.xml')
tree = tree.getroot()
t = tostring(tree)
t = t.lower()
tree = ET.fromstring(t)
```